# Customize Fusion Table Heatmaps Like Regular Maps API Heatmaps?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-api, google-fusion-tables

I am combining the Maps Javascript API with Fusion Tables to make a heatmap. The problem is, when zoomed in past a very high level the heatmap looks very sparse.

I'd like to modify the maxIntensity and radius the way you can with regular non-fusion heatmaps in the Maps API. Is it possible to modify these parameters and where would you do so in the code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, you can't customize the Fusion Tables heatmaps layer like the Heat Map Layer in the Google Maps API.

Here's some sample code for getting your data out of a Fusion Table and calling a heatmap layer: 
https://googledrive.com/host/0B5KVZ6J1ohN_Q3ZqVkFGSGZ2cEE/heatmaps%20code/

-Rebecca

Comment: That was exactly the example I needed. Thank you !